# Looking up parent item based on a bill of materials

Tags: sql

I'm trying to figure out how to put together a SQL statement that will let me find an end-item in our database based on its bill of materials. I guess you could say this is like a reverse BOM lookup question.

My table structure is pretty simple.

```
-End-item table
-Component table
-Linking table to tie together multiple components to an end item record.
```

The data I have is just the component list, and I want to find the end item. Since every bill of material is unique it has to match the bill of materials perfectly ie exact number of components and exact matches to the component SKU numbers. In some cases 2 end-items might use all the same components, but one of them just uses an extra part or two that makes the end-item SKU number different, so it has to account for that. That is, again, it has to match the BOM perfectly.

If not an outright answer, could someone at least steer me on the correct path to finding one?

------ UPDATE ----------
Table structure would be something like this.

```
    ManufacturedPart
,--------------------,
|   ID  |  PART_NUM  |  
|--------------------|
|   1   |  V3175-01  |
|   2   |  V3367-01  |
|   3   |  V3988-01  |
|   4   |  V3175-CV  |
`--------------------`

   Component
,--------------------,
|   ID  |  COMP_NUM  |  
|--------------------|
|   1   |  V3175     |
|   2   |  V3367     |
|   3   |  V3369     |
|   4   |  V3114     |
|   5   |  V3370     |
|   6   |  V4060     |
|   7   |  V3550     |
|   8   |  V3988     |
`--------------------`

            ManufacturedComponent
,-------------------------------------------------,
|   ID  |  MANUFACTURED_PART_ID  |  COMPONENT_ID  |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|   1   |          1             |       1        |
|   2   |          1             |       4        |
|   3   |          1             |       6        |
|   4   |          2             |       2        |
|   5   |          2             |       3        |
|   6   |          2             |       5        |
|   7   |          2             |       7        |
|   8   |          3             |       1        |
|   9   |          3             |       8        |
|   10  |          4             |       1        |
|   11  |          4             |       4        |
`-------------------------------------------------`
```

Assuming I have only the COMP_NUMs (component numbers) to search with I want to match back to the ManufacturedPart that contains that exact list of components.

So some examples: If I have components V3175, V3114, and V4060, it should match back to V3175-01 manufactured part. But, if I only have components V3175 and V3114 it should match back to V3175-CV manufactured part. If I have components V3367, V3369, V3370, and V3550 it should match back to manufactured part V3367-01.

I have no SQL written at all yet as I'm unsure of how to break the problem down..

Comment: Can you post the SQL statement that you have written thus far?

Comment: Please post sample data from those tables and your desired result too. Looking at your table names I have no idea where I would find a "Bom" and how that relates to "Sku" and what an "End-Item" is. Nor do I know what a "Bom lookup" is, but I probably just have never worked with bill of material data before.

Comment: Yes you're right. Sorry about the wonky terminology. I updated the original post to include example data.

Comment: That makes more sense. What RDBMS are you using? Sql Server, Mysql, Postgres, Oracle?

Comment: Here's a [rextester Sandbox](http://rextester.com/JMEX99171) to save others some time

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Right now it's just in MS Access as I'm doing some testing, but eventually I'll be moving it to SQL Server.

Comment: I _kind_ of have a solution going here: [SQLSANDBOX](http://rextester.com/CZK10717). I'm sure this could be refined to be better. So what I have to do here is supply the part numbers **and** the number of components I'm matching against in the IN and HAVING clauses, respectively. Is there a way to rewrite this so that I wouldn't have to supply the number of components I'm putting into the IN clause? Is there a function in SQL Server or something that could tell me how many values I have in there, and then I could insert that into the HAVING clause instead of doing it explicitly?